# Doxygen - How to include code file in page

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to document a library I'm writing using Doxygen, and I've decided to try to write a basic tutorial. I've created separate pages for it. Now, I want to include full files in code blocks. I found the `@include` command, but that doesn't work. Nothing appears except a thin blue bar the length of the page. I've tried giving it just the name of the file (`filename.ext`), as well as with the relative path to the file, with both front and back slash (`Source/filename.ext` and `Source\filename.ext`).

Comment: Can you post a small example what you tried including the changes to the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile)? Did you get any warnings? Did you set the `EXAMPLE_PATH` in the Doxyfile?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I hadn't noticed `@include` used files from `EXAMPLE_PATH`, I had just assumed it took files from the "Doxygen file list".

Comment: Please don't add this as an answer or otherwise reformulate. It is indeed a bit strange that `\include` uses the `EXAMPLE_PATH` but this is historical and a warning should have been given.

Comment: @albert I don't understand what you mean. Why does this not work as an answer? I just re-read the Doxygen special commands page section on `@include`, and noticed it talked about it taking files from `EXAMPLE_PATH`.

Comment: Well I see this not as  a real problem it was more usage, therefore I made the comment.

Comment: @albert Usage was the problem, and my answer is how I fixed that usage problem.